# Continue to Controller even if request validation fails

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I have this controller with its own Request Class and Rules to validation. I need it to enter the Controller even if the validation fails.
I need to create the object even if it's wrong. But also send back the errors to the user.

```
 /**
 * Ebdn_gnl - Store
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Ebdn\Http\Requests\EbdnGnlRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
//public function store(Request $request)
public function store(EbdnGnlRequest $request)
{
    dump($request->all());
    return response("Api under construction", 200);
}
```

Comment: could you try sending `Accept: application/json` header in your request?

Comment: Yes indeed. And in case of failed validation it throws 422 error with error messages. 
But in my case I want is to continue to my controller, do my stuff with the request and then return the errors.

Comment: you can set `$redirect` variable to your route to forward it to your Controller if validation fails?

Comment: Redirecting wont do me any good I will stumble at the same thing.
But I found a solution I'm satisfied with. I put it in the answers if you wanna check it.
Thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it !!

in my Request Class I need to overwride the failedValidation function to make it merge the errors to the request (So I can access them in my Controller) instead of throwing error.

> class EbdnGnlRequest extends FormRequest
>   {

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $this->merge(['errors' => $validator->errors()]);
}
```

Comment: May I know the full namespace for the `Validator` class you used?

Comment: you can use "php artisan make:request <YourRequestClass>"
And in the Controller action you inject it.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can put a message inside your Request, for each rule:

```
public function message(){}
```

Good luck!